# Better way to import data from REST API to SQL DB using Python?

Tags: python, sql, azure

I've written some python code to extract data from a rest api and load them in an Azure SQL database. But this process is taking almost half a hour for 20,000 lines. Is there a more efficient way of doing this? I'm thinking maybe extract the data as json file and put it in blob storate then use azure data factory to load the data into SQL, but have no idea how to code this way.

```
def manualJournalLineItems(tenantid):
endpoint = "api.xro/2.0/manualjournals/?page=1"

result = (getAPI(endpoint,token,tenantid))
page = 1
while result['ManualJournals']:
    endpoint = "api.xro/2.0/manualjournals/?page="+str(page)
    result = (getAPI(endpoint,token,tenantid))
    for inv in result['ManualJournals']:
        for li in inv['JournalLines']:
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO [server].dbo.[Xero_ManualJournalLines](ManualJournalID,AccountID,Description,LineAmount,TaxAmount,AccountCode,Region) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",inv['ManualJournalID'],li['AccountID'],li.get('Description',''),li.get('LineAmount',0),li.get('TaxAmount',0),li.get('AccountCode',0),tenantid)
            conn.commit()
    page = int(page)+1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. append() the values to a list and insert the list into SQL with executemany()

Answer (score 0):

If Python is not a mandatory requirement, yes, you can use Data Factory.
You will need to create a pipeline  with the following components:

- 'Copy Data' Activity
- Source Dataset (REST API)
- Sink Dataset (Azure SQL)

** **Also may I know where is your REST API hosted? Is it within Azure through App Service? If not, you will also need to setup a [Self-Hosted Integration Runtime]**[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime)

You can refer to the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-portal#create-a-pipeline) which copies data from **Blob storage** to **Azure SQL**

You can also follow my screenshots below which is to create REST API as a Source.

1. Create a new pipeline.
2. Type 'copy' in the **'Activity' search box**. Drag the 'Copy Data' activity to the pipeline
   [image]
3. Click on **'Source' tab**, and click on 'New' to create a new Source Dataset.
   [image]
4. Type **'REST'** in the **'data source' search box**.
   [image]
5. In the **'REST' dataset window**, click on **'Connection' tab**. Click on 'New' to create a linked service to point to the REST API.
   [image]
6. Here fill up the **credentials** to the REST API.
   [image]
7. Continue setting up the **Sink dataset to point to the Azure SQL** and test out your pipeline to make sure it works. Hope it helps!

Comment: I do use data factory for other ETL processes, but data factory does not handle pagination very well. So my python script is actually a work around because data factory cannot get the job done on this one. I opened a ticket with Azure and they couldn't help me make this work with their product.

Comment: Also I have a hard time integrating anything with Oauth2 and refresh token into Data Factory.

Comment: Hey Joe, sorry, I probably misread your question. Thought you have yet to tried out Data Factory instead ;). Good to know these things you have been experiencing. Will love to learn out more on what other alternatives others can provide to resolve.